# When is $\{A,B\}$ $\cap$-stable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem** Let $A, B \subset X$. Compare $\delta(\{A, B\})$ and $\sigma(\{A, B\})$. When are they equal?

**My answer** It follows from a proposition (in my textbook) that $\delta(\{A, B\}) \subset \sigma(\{A, B\}) $ is always true.
It follows from a theorem (in my textbook) that $\delta(\{A, B\}) = \sigma(\{A, B\})$ **iff** $\{A, B\}$ is $\cap$-stable (definition: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stable_under_Intersection). So the question I have to ask myself is "when is $\{A, B\}$ $\cap$-stable ? ". It is clear for me that this is the case if $A=B$. But is apparently also true when $A = B^c$. The intersection in this case will be $A \cap B = \emptyset$, but $\emptyset \not\in \{A,B\}$. So I do not understand how $\{A, B\}$ is $\cap$-stable if $A=B^c$. This is my question.

NB $\delta (\{A,B\})$ is the [Dynkin system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) generated by $\{A, B\}$ and $\sigma (\{A,B\})$ is the [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) generated by $\{A, B\}$.

Comment: Please don't use the [set-theory] tag when it is irrelevant.

Comment: @AsafKaragila i used because i thought jt was

Comment: Questions involving sets are not questions about set theory.

Comment: Could you state precisely the theorem in your textbook to which you refer?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin "If $\mathscr{G} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ is stable under finite intersections, then $\delta(\mathscr{G})=\sigma(\mathscr{G})$"

Comment: I don't see any "if and only if" in this statement...

Comment: Oh, yes. Right. But that does not answer my question.